# Logback configuration error detected: no applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath is [[configuration][springProfile]]

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu, logback

I have a Springboot application with Logback. This war is running in a Liberty webserver in a docker container

Versions:
Springboot 2.5.3
Logback 1.2.3

I am seeing a weird behavior where if I run this container on a Mac or Redhat, the application starts up fine and logs as expected.
However, when the same docker container is run in Ubuntu, I am seeing the following error from Logback's Joran interpreter :

```
...
08:07:53,308 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework] to WARN
08:07:53,308 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate] to WARN
08:07:53,308 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [springfox] to WARN
08:07:53,313 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@88:32 - no applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile]]
08:07:53,313 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@89:51 - no applicable action for [root], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][root]]
08:07:53,314 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@90:73 - no applicable action for [appender-ref], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][root][appender-ref]]
08:07:53,314 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
08:07:53,314 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5b3de2a2 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
[err] Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from '/logback-spring.xml'
[err] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@88:32 - no applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@89:51 - no applicable action for [root], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][root]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@90:73 - no applicable action for [appender-ref], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][root][appender-ref]]
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:179)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:57)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:316)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:282)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:240)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
[err]   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
[err]   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
[err]   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
[err]   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners$$Lambda$71/0x000000006c31f840.accept(Unknown Source)
[err]   at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1270)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
[err]   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
[err]   at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2550)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:822)
```

Here is my logback configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="console-json"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder name="LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder"
                 class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <timestamp/>
                <version/>
                <message/>
                <loggerName>
                    <shortenedLoggerNameLength>20
                    </shortenedLoggerNameLength>
                </loggerName>
                <threadName/>
                <logLevel/>
                <logLevelValue/>
                <callerData>
                    <fieldName>caller</fieldName>
                    <classFieldName>class</classFieldName>
                    <methodFieldName>method</methodFieldName>
                    <fileFieldName>file</fileFieldName>
                    <lineFieldName>line</lineFieldName>
                </callerData>
                <stackTrace>
                    <throwableConverter
                            class="net.logstash.logback.stacktrace.ShortenedThrowableConverter">
                        <maxDepthPerThrowable>100</maxDepthPerThrowable>
                        <maxLength>10000</maxLength>
                        <shortenedClassNameLength>30
                        </shortenedClassNameLength>
                        <rootCauseFirst>true</rootCauseFirst>
                        <inlineHash>true</inlineHash>
                    </throwableConverter>
                </stackTrace>
                <stackHash/>
                <jsonMessage/>
                <mdc/>
                <contextMap/>
                <tags/>
                <logstashMarkers/>
                <arguments>
                    <includeNonStructuredArguments>true
                    </includeNonStructuredArguments>
                    <nonStructuredArgumentsFieldPrefix>prefix
                    </nonStructuredArgumentsFieldPrefix>
                </arguments>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="springfox" level="WARN"/>

    <springProfile name="prod">
        <root level="${logback_root_level:-INFO}">
            <appender-ref ref="${logback_root_appender:-console-json}"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="minimal">
        <root level="${logback_root_level:-WARN}">
            <appender-ref ref="${logback_root_appender:-console-json}"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Check if your logback file is a spring logback file like `logback-spring.xml`.
Had the exact same issue fixed it by changing the file name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: More details in the Spring documentation in section  : "83.1 Configure Logback for Logging", link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging

Answer (score 5):

From Spring Boot [documentation](https://ERROR%20in%20ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:71%20-%20no%20applicable%20action%20for%20%5BspringProperty%5D,%20current%20ElementPath%20is%20%5B%5Bconfiguration%5D%5BspringProperty%5D%5D%20ERROR%20in%20ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:71%20-%20no%20applicable%20action%20for%20%5BspringProfile%5D,%20current%20ElementPath%20is%20%5B%5Bconfiguration%5D%5BspringProfile%5D%5D):

> Because the standard logback.xml configuration file is loaded too
> early, you cannot use extensions in it. You need to either use
> logback-spring.xml or define a logging.config property.
>
> The extensions cannot be used with Logback’s configuration scanning.
> If you attempt to do so, making changes to the configuration file
> results in an error similar to one of the following being logged:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:71 - no applicable action for [springProperty], current ElementPath is [[configuration][springProperty]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:71 - no applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath is [[configuration][springProfile]]
```

Then, since you're using Spring Boots's extension tags, you need to name your file as `logback-spring.xml`, so it will be loaded at the properly time.

Comment: Yepp, this is the correct answer, with a proper EXPLANATION.

Answer (score 2):

I had changed file name to logback-spring.xml ,then is ok.